# Why is an api call returning different things in windows and linux?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am trying to get retrieve some data from a website api. It works out alright in my personal machine with Windows, however when I use another VM with Ubuntu in GCP it crashes

Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.buda.com/api/v2/markets/ETH-COP/order_book'
answer = requests.get(url)
print(url.status_code)
print(url.txt)
```

In windows this is the output

```json
200
'{"order_book":{"asks":[["9300974.95","0.017059589"],["9300988.98","0.02104"],["9301000.0","0.0456"],["9304101.0","0.035"],["9305121.0","0.057411325"],["9488101.0","0.025"],["9491000.0","0.025"],["9596121.0","0.03"],["9766963.93","0.054399644"],["9887041.7","0.000146739"],["9887846.1","0.086726678"],["10000000.0","0.217447367"],["10042060.0","0.01"],["10102060.0","0.01248862"],["10149880.0","0.042914"],["10194000.0","0.095735001"],["10200000.0","0.020424454"]}}
```

And this is the output in GCP Virtual machine with Ubuntu

```html
[503]
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: ant
ialiased;}
    h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
more html...
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The website `buda.com` is protected by CloudFlare.

CloudFlare is allowing traffic from your Windows machine's network connection and denying traffic from your GCP VM. This is likely because CloudFlare trusts your Windows machine's public IP address but associates your GCM VM's IP with automated web crawlers or other undesirable traffic.

If you want to access `buda.com` via a computer program, you will need to connect via an IP address that CloudFlare or buda.com trusts.

Alternatively, humans using JavaScript-capable web browsers can sometimes fill out a CAPTCHA and be allowed to continue to the protected website.